# Why is the gradient of a local graph representation $0$ at point $0$ after orientation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been working on the local graph representation for a smooth boundary:

[image]

If I choose my coordinates such that $x_0=0$ and have this 
$\Omega\cap B(0,r)=\left\{x\in B(0,r): x_n>h(x')\right\}$

$\partial\Omega\cap B(0,r)=\left\{x\in B(0,r): x_n=h(x')\right\}.$
Then $h(0)=0$, but why is the gradient of function $h$ zero at the point zero with respect to the first $n-1$ coordinates, that is why is $\nabla h(0)=0$?

Comment: This certainly doesn't have to be the case, but you can arrange for it to be true.

Comment: @Ted   Can you try to explain how I could arrange this to be true? I think it has something to do with the tangent plane at $0$ to be $T_0(\partial\Omega)=\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

Comment: Precisely. Just rotate your coordinate system to make the tangent plane of the boundary horizontal at the origin.

Comment: @TedShifrin Now I see, I just didn't realize the horizontality of the plane, thank you :)